# Mixing sound files of different size

Tags: iphone, objective-c, audio

I want to mix audio files of different size into a one single .wav file without clipping any file.,i.e. The resulting file size should be equal to the largest sized file of all.

There is a sample through which we can mix files of same size

[(http://www.modejong.com/iOS/#ex4 )(Example 4)].

I modified the code to get the mixed file as a .wav file.

But  I am not able to understand that how to modify this code for unequal sized files.
If someone can help me out with some code snippet,i'll be really thankful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be as easy as sending all the files to the mixer simultaneously.  When any single file gets to the end, just treat it as if the remainder is filled with zeroes.   When all files get to the end, you are done.

Note that the example code says it returns an error if there would be clipping (the sum of the waves is greater than the max representable value.). This condition is more likely if you are mixing multiple inputs.  The best way around it is to create some ["headroom"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Headroom_%28audio_signal_processing%29) in the input waves.  You can do either do this in preprocessing, by ensuring that each wave's volume is no more than X% of maximum.  (~80-90%, depending on number of inputs.).   The other way is to do it dynamically in the mixer code by multiplying each sample by some value <1.0 as you add it to the mix.

If you are selecting the waves to mix at runtime and failure due to clipping is unacceptable, you will need to modify the sample code to pin the values at max/min instead  of returning an error.  Don't just let them overflow or you will get noisy artifacts.

(Clipping creates artifacts as well, but when you haven't created enough headroom before mixing, it is definitely preferrable to overflow. It is a more familiar-sounding type of distortion, similar to what you get when you overdrive your speakers.  See [this wikipedia article on clipping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clipping_%28audio%29#Digital_clipping):

> Clipping is preferable to the alternative in digital systems—wrapping—which occurs if the digital hardware is allowed to "overflow", ignoring the most significant bits of the magnitude, and sometimes even the sign of the sample value, resulting in gross distortion of the signal.

Comment: Pinning to max/min sounds pretty horrible too!

Answer (score 0):

How I'd do it:

Much like the `mix_buffers` function that you linked to, but pass in 2 parameters for `mixbufferNumSamples`.  Iterate over the whole of the longer of the two buffers.  When the index has gone beyond the end of the shorter buffer, simply set the sample from that buffer to `0` for the rest of the function.

If you *must* avoid clipping *and* do it in real-time *and* you know nothing else about the two sounds, you must provide enough headroom.  The simplest method is by halving each of the samples before mixing:

```
 mixed = s1/2 + s2/2;
```

This ensures that the resultant mixed sample won't overflow an `int16_t`.  It will have the side effect of making everything quieter though.

If you can run it offline, you can calculate a scale factor to apply to both waveforms which will keep the peaks when summed below the maximum allowed value.

Or you could mix them all at full volume to an `int32_t` buffer, keeping track of the largest (magnitude) mixed sample and then go back through the buffer multiplying each sample by a scale factor which will make that extreme sample *just* reach the +32767/-32768 limits.